# How to display the number of remaining child in wrap widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a widget that shows a list of several containers. Since the width of containers may vary, it should be moved to the next line if the width is full. Moreover, I want to set the maximum line of this widget to 2, and display the number of remaining containers if the children exceed the maxLine.

Desired Result:
[image: Desired Result]

---

So I used the Wrap widget, and I used the boxConstraint property of Container to realize the maxLine. (reference : [How to render a specific number of lines for Wrap in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622663/how-to-render-a-specific-number-of-lines-for-wrap-in-flutter))
However, I cannot find the way to display the number of remaining containers. I want to find a way to get the number of remaining containers and how to set the position of the number.

Comment: There is a second post `extend_wrap`, does that work for you?

Comment: I used the Wrap widget with BoxConstraints instead of using the extended_wrap package. The main problem is that the number of remaining containers(for example, '+2') is not displayed harmonically with the containers in the Wrap widget. I want to find a way to get the number of remaining containers and how to set the position of the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wrap_and_more](https://pub.dev/packages/wrap_and_more) package.

Example:

```dart
WrapAndMore(
  maxRow: 2,
  spacing: 8.0,
  runSpacing: 8.0,
  overflowWidget: (restChildrenCount) {
    return Text(
      '+$restChildrenCount',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    );
  },
  children: [
    for (final text
        in List.generate(7, (i) => 'Category ${i + 1}')
          ..insert(4, 'Category with long name'))
      Chip(label: Text(text)),
  ],
)
```

[image]

---

**WARNING**: This package is using GetX. Might be best to just learn the logic of the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work well in my environment(Flutter 3.16.0, emulator iOS 17.2). I directly copied your code and run it, but the result is like this : 
https://imgur.com/a/ELvQh5r
It seems that this package is not stable yet.

Comment: Hmm weird, that could be related to the constraining of the parent widget. Try fixing with `SizedBox` or other `Box` variant widget. Or you could see how the package is implemented and modify it for your own

Comment: I set the parent widget to SizedBox that occupies the full width. It seems the problem is more related to the 'WrapAndMoreController' and rendering. I'll see the original code of the package. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Nice catch. I think the good thing about this package is that it's always giving the correct number of the children that are not shown

Comment: Just found a red flag of that package, the package is using GetX  Best might be to just see the logic of the implementation